# Deciphering datetime discrepancy between application output and server

Tags: python, linux, datetime, redis

In a Django/Python application where I'm using redis, I do:

```
my_server = redis.Redis(connection_pool=POOL)
updated_at = time.time()
object_hash = "np:"+str(object_id)
sorted_set = "sn:"+str(user_id)
my_server.zadd(sorted_set, object_hash, updated_at)
```

This is straight forward. Essentially, I'm maintaining a sorted set that contains objects sorted by time of updating the object.

The problem is if I used `redis-cli` to get `zrange sorted_set 0 -1 WITHSCORES`, the `score` shows time that is precisely **5 hours older** than what was originally in `updated_at`.

e.g. if `updated_at` was fed `1479646405.21`, the redis sorted set score ends up being `1479628405.497179` (as per output from `redis-cli`). I.e. 5 hours behind. This looks like an issue of timezone - my location's ahead by 5 hours from UTC.

My question is: *why does the score jump back 5 hours when updating the redis server?* Whenever I `print` the `updated_at` variable from within my application, I get the correct number. Is this a Linux issue (the OS my application resides on is Ubuntu 14.04), and if so, can you explain precisely what could be going on? Being a beginner, I'm trying to understand the dynamics at play here. Thanks!